# Running count of current values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, count

I've got code that `counts` the amount of values currently occurring. It achieves this by parsing through the `df` to see if they occur again.

So for the `df` below I'm counting how many values are currently occurring in `Col['Area']`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Code' : ['A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B','A','A'],            
    'Area' : ['Home','Home','Shops','Park','Cafe','Shops','Home','Cafe','Work','Park'],  
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['u'] = df[::-1].groupby('Area').Area.cumcount()

ids = [1]
seen = set([df.iloc[0].Area])
dec = False
for val, u in zip(df.Area[1:], df.u[1:]):
    ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
    seen.add(val)
    dec = u == 0

df['On'] = ids
```

The problem is I only want to apply this function to the value `'A'` in `Col['Code']`.

I can do the following but this cuts my `df` down.

```
df = df[df.Code == 'A']
```

I'm hoping to produce the following;

```
  Code   Area  u On
0    A   Home  2  1
1    A   Home  1  1
2    B  Shops      
3    A   Park  1  2
4    B   Cafe      
5    B  Shops      
6    A   Home  0  2
7    B   Cafe      
8    A   Work  0  2
9    A   Park  0  2
```

Can I alter this to add `['Code']`

```
df['u'] = df[::-1].groupby('Area').Area.cumcount()
```

Comment: Like this: `df['u'] = df[df.Code == 'A'][::-1].groupby('Area').Area.cumcount()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this code to get your desired ouptut

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
'Code' : ['A','A','B','A','B','B','A','B','A','A'],            
'Area' : ['Home','Home','Shops','Park','Cafe','Shops','Home','Cafe','Work','Park'],  
 })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1 = df[df.Code == 'A'].copy()

df1['u'] = df1[::-1].groupby('Area').Area.cumcount()

ids = [1]
seen = set([df1.iloc[0].Area])
dec = False
for val, u in zip(df1.Area[1:], df1.u[1:]):
    ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
    seen.add(val)
    dec = u == 0
 df1['On'] = ids

 df1 = df1.reindex(df.index).fillna(df)
 print (df1.fillna(""))

 # Output
    Code  Area  u On
 0    A   Home  2  1
 1    A   Home  1  1
 2    B  Shops      
 3    A   Park  1  2
 4    B   Cafe      
 5    B  Shops      
 6    A   Home  0  2
 7    B   Cafe      
 8    A   Work  0  2
 9    A   Park  0  1
```

Comment: Sir I am sorry feel such a way, But I have been updating my code, if you feel so just report me / downvote . I don't mind if you answer I answer as long we could help user to understand it better. Thank you

Comment: I am moving over to another question please do follow me over there (could be among Any programming language Python/Js/ML anything). Thanks and nice talking to you !!

Comment: Hmmm, maybe  Iam wrong my solution is copied by you. But if you are author, please add explanation of code and it means you understand it. If not, code is copied :(